# Set the text of the button pressed. Android development

Tags: android

I'm learning to create apps for android. I want to edit the text of the button that is pressed.

What I have right now works, but I want to know if there is a better way. Specifically for the lines

```
Button vb = (Button) v;
vb.setText(et1.getText().toString());
```

what is the view "v" that is being passed in? Why can't I do something like v.setText();

```
package mobile.threethingstodo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button b1, b2, b3;
EditText et1;
String text = "default";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initialize();
}

public void initialize() {
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Button vb = (Button) v;
    vb.setText(et1.getText().toString());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> what is the view "v" that is being passed in?

The `View` passed to `onClick()` is the `View` which was clicked. This is a great way to write this program since the action performed is similar for all of your buttons.

> Why can't I do something like v.setText();

Because the `View` class does not have a `setText()` metohd. If you try to do this, you will get a compiler error.

Comment: The `View` that is passed to `onClick()` is a button, right? A button is a view...

Comment: @rgkirch Yes, in this case, the `View` passed to `onClick()` is each of the buttons with which you registered the `OnClickListener`. However, you can register an `OnClickListener` with **any** `View`, even those which are not buttons. You cannot assume that the `View` passed in will always be a button.

Comment: Can I verify that it is a Button and if it is then call `setText()`?

Comment: @rgkirch In this case, you don't need to "verify" anything. You **know** that the `View` is a `Button` because you have only registered your `OnClickListener` to `Button` views. This is why you can safely cast the `View` to a `Button` and then call `setText()`. This is exactly what your code does in the OP.

Comment: @rgkirch In a more complex app, you will probably have multiple `OnClickListener`s (most likely one for each `View` that needs one), so you still won't need to verify what the view is that is passed to `onClick()`. You will know which views can be passed to it.

Comment: I think I was expecting there to be a way to call `setText()` on the view directly as opposed to creating another button "vb" to copy into. So, you think what I have is good? Thank you.

Comment: @rgkirch Yes what you have is exactly how to do it. As I said in my answer, you cannot call `setText()` directly because the `View` class does not have this method. I strongly suggest that you familiarize yourself with the Android documentation which shows what methods are available for each class.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast View to TextView as it extends View. Then you will be introduced another problem when you want to handle multiple click event. When facing that problem, learn how each view has an I'd then use that Id to identify your target view.

Comment: Personally, I prefer to set different event handlers when each button requires different logic.

Comment: It's a matter of preferences, there's no absolute right or wrong here :) Whatever float your boat ;-)

Comment: Exactly! I'm just noting my preference here as an alternative.

Comment: In this case, it's the same logic for each button.